# ABFS hadoop-azure AzureBlobFileSystem.listStatus(path) takes too much time (doesn't return) for directories with too many entries

Tags: java, azure, hadoop, azure-blob-storage

I am using `hadoop-azure` to access Azure blob file system (ABFS) instance, specifically when I try to list all files/directories in a specific path, it works normally for normal directories with a limited number of files/directories.

I came to a case when the path contains too many entries (thousands), the method  `AzureBlobFileSystem.listStatus(path)` never returns.

It works well when the number of files/directories isn't large. I wonder if I can solve this issue, can I enhance or configure this listing to be faster or more efficient. Is there any hadoop configuration to use?

Comment: Mahmoud -can you drop an email to omkarksa@gmail.com about this -he's @ microsoft and they want to identify/fix the issue? thanks

Answer (score 0):

File a bug report on apache JIRA; hadoop module. Provide more details about the directory structure. And hadoop version. This may be [HADOOP-16269](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-16269). 
.